# Get Notification from API flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification

I have a screen named Alert where i recieved Notification from server.As you see each alert placed in Card . My goal is How to display this card as notification for user. All things works fine but i would like to get alert as notification when my app in background. I don't need any button action in my screen to active notification. I want to recieve notification automatically when it come from server. How i can configure Notification code to get that correctly ?

this my code :

```
class _AlerteState extends State<Alerte> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {

  void callbackDispatcher() {
    Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
      if (task == 'uniqueKey') {
        ///do the task in Backend for how and when to send notification
        var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.GET_ALERT));
        Map dataComingFromTheServer = json.decode(response.body);

        final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
            FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
        const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
            AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id', 'your channel name',
                'your channel description',
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
                showWhen: false);
        const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
            NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            0,
            dataComingFromTheServer['data']['first_name'],
            dataComingFromTheServer['data']['email'],
            platformChannelSpecifics,
            payload: 'item x');
      }
      return Future.value(true);
    });
  }

  void main() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings();
    final MacOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsMacOS =
        MacOSInitializationSettings();
    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
            macOS: initializationSettingsMacOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);

    Workmanager.initialize(callbackDispatcher, isInDebugMode: true);

    Workmanager.registerPeriodicTask(
      "1",
      "uniqueKey",
      frequency: Duration(minutes: 15),
    );
    runApp(MyApp());
  }

  Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
    }
  }
 @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color color;
    Widget body = new FutureBuilder<UserAlert>(
        future: boxApi.getAlert(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.alerts.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var alert = snapshot.data.alerts[index].alertLevel;
                  switch (alert) {
                    case "danger":
                      color = Colors.red;
                      break;
                    case "warning":
                      color = Colors.yellow;
                      break;
                    case "info":
                      color = Colors.green;
                      break;
                    default:
                      color = Colors.grey;
                  }
                  var boxName = snapshot.data.alerts[index].boxName;
                  var date = snapshot.data.alerts[index].alertDate;
                  var time = snapshot.data.alerts[index].alertTime;
                  var description =
                      snapshot.data.alerts[index].alertDescription;
                  return Card(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
ListTile(
                          title: Text("$date" + "  " + "$time"),
                          subtitle: Text("$description"),
                          trailing: Text("$boxName"),
                          leading: Transform.translate(
                            offset: const Offset(-15.0, 0.0),
                            child: Container(
                           
                              color: color,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                                height: 100,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                });
          } else {
            return new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        });

    return Scaffold(
      
        body: body);
  }
}
```

and this is the Screen :

[image]